# How can cookie/session authentication be used in wp-json fetch request?

Tags: json, authentication

I've written a `/wp-json` path like:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'myplugin', 'foo', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => function( $data ) {
      // if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
      //   return array();
      // }
      return array('dummy_data');
    }
  ) );
} );
```

I can retreive the data using the es6-style [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) like:

```
fetch('/wp-json/myplugin/foo', {credentials: 'include'})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
```

This works dandy.

However, if I un-comment the `if (!is_user_logged_in())...` check, it never passes.  I send the `Cookie` header in this request, but wordpress doesn't seem to do cookie/session-style authentication and `is_user_logged_in()` is never `true.

I know that there is the nonce mechanism, but this API will only ever be fetched from the wordpress site and I want to use the cookie/session mechanism.

How can I authenticate the user against their server session when the request is coming from the `fetch` or xhr API javascript mehanism?

Comment: See the relevant section of the docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#cookie-authentication

Comment: @JacobPeattie That's why  I mentioned nonces.  Can you do it without nonces?

Comment: The nonce tells the api to use cookies. Please read the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading more, thanks to Jacob's link and more googling, it turns out that wordpress "nonces" aren't actually nonces.  [Nonces are to be used once](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce), but wordpress "nonces" are allowed to be used an unlimited number of times for 2 "ticks", which normally means between 12 and 24 hours.  These wordpress "nonces" are actually tied to a session and hence give me exactly what I want, since I can reuse the wordpress "nonce" for a period of time.

Comment: any chance for a complete example of your solution? I didn't quite sure how you managed to apply the nonce.

Comment: Apologies, I don't remember the exact details.  You can look at [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#cookie-authentication) and it looks like you create a "nonce" with `wp_create_nonce` on the php side and then send that "nonce" back using a javascript `fetch` with header `'X-WP-Nonce'`.  The details are in that documentation.